# Copying data from multiple Excel workbooks into a master using Applescript

Tags: excel, applescript

I am trying to combine the values from a series of Excel files into one master file. Each smaller file has a header row and then 144 rows of data, columns A-J. The script is supposed to loop through each one, get the data minus the headers, and then find the next rows without data in the master workbook and insert the input data. There are problems however in both the pasting section and when I try to save the master file.

Trying to choose multiple files to copy gives me a weird worksheet where the data is copied multiple times from different input worksheets (not sure if this is related to the clipboard not clearing properly?). And then at the end, it asks me if I want to save the master excel workbook, so somehow it looks like it’s skipping the “save” line (even though sometimes that part works?).

```
set whichFile to choose file with prompt "choose files to copy" with multiple selections allowed
set mainBook to choose file with prompt "choose master file"

    repeat with eachFile in whichFile

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        activate
        open eachFile

        -- get data to copy
        set theRange to range "A2:J145" of active sheet of workbook eachFile
        select theRange
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down

    end tell

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        -- write data into excel
        open mainBook
        set lastFilledCell to get end (range "A105536") of active sheet of mainBook direction toward the top
        set insertPoint to get offset lastFilledCell row offset 1
        select insertPoint
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down

    end tell

    tell application "Finder" to set clipboard to {}

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

        save mainBook in file mainBook with overwrite
        close workbooks

    end tell

end repeat
```

Sorry about any glaring errors, I am very new to coding. I know for example that it’s better to rely on setting values directly instead of using the clipboard (especially with keystrokes) but I couldn’t get that to work at all.

Comment: You can use a VBA macro. All the code you need is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963284/applescript-to-combine-multiple-excel-files-into-a-single-worksheet

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yes, should have realized a VBA macro would be easier than going through applescripts. Have also just found an Excel add-in that will do the same - there are Windows and Mac versions: http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/addins/mergemac.htm