# How to loop through files in a folder Excel Mac 2016

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

I'm trying to combine several excel files into one. For this I've been using and modifying an old answer I [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963284/applescript-to-combine-multiple-excel-files-into-a-single-worksheet/11975711#11975711), but I ran into trouble while running it on Excel 2016 for Mac (it worked ok with Excel 2011 for Mac, with some changes).

In Excel 2016 (Mac), the following code runs through the loop once, after which it prints the name of the first file in the selected folder, but then it stops.

In Excel 2011 (Mac), it correctly prints the names of all files in the selected folder.

```
Sub wat()
Dim FilesFolder As String, strFile As String

'mac excel 2011
'FilesFolder = MacScript("(choose folder with prompt ""dis"") as string")

'mac excel 2016
FilesFolder = MacScript("return posix path of (choose folder with prompt ""dat"") as string")

If FilesFolder = "" Then Exit Sub

strFile = Dir(FilesFolder)

Do While Len(strFile) > 0

    Debug.Print "1. " & strFile

    strFile = Dir

Loop

MsgBox "ded"
End Sub
```

So, I'm pretty new at this, but it looks to me like `strFile = Dir` is not working properly.

I looked at the Ron deBruin page:
[Loop through Files in Folder on a Mac (Dir for Mac Excel)](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac013.htm)
but to be honest that was a little too complicated for me to comprehend and modify to my needs.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks for the patience!

Comment: this helps? http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac013.htm

Comment: Hi @cyboashu, thanks for the answer. I'd already seen the page you posted (its in the original question), and while it seems really helpful for the long term, its well above my level right now, and I wasn't able to modify it to my needs. Is it the only way to loop through the files in a folder with excel 2016?

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFileNames()

'Modified from http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac013.htm


Dim folderPath As String 
Dim FileNameFilter As String
Dim ScriptToRun As String
Dim MyFiles As String
Dim Extensions As String
Dim Level As String
Dim MySplit As Variant
Dim FileInMyFiles As Long
Dim Fstr As String
Dim LastSep As String


'mac excel 2016

'Get the directory
On Error Resume Next 'MJN
folderPath = MacScript("choose folder as string") 'MJN
If folderPath = "" Then Exit Sub 'MJN
On Error GoTo 0 'MJN

'Set up default parameters to get one level of Folders
'All files

Level = "1"
Extensions = ".*"

'Set up filter for all file types
FileNameFilter = "'.*/[^~][^/]*\\." & Extensions & "$' "  'No Filter

'Set up the folder path to allow to work in script
folderPath = MacScript("tell text 1 thru -2 of " & Chr(34) & folderPath & _
                           Chr(34) & " to return quoted form of it's POSIX Path")
folderPath = Replace(folderPath, "'\''", "'\\''")

'Run the script
        ScriptToRun = ScriptToRun & "do shell script """ & "find -E " & _
                      folderPath & " -iregex " & FileNameFilter & "-maxdepth " & _
                      Level & """ "

'Set the String MyFiles to the result of the script for processing
On Error Resume Next
MyFiles = MacScript(ScriptToRun)
On Error GoTo 0

'Clear the fist four columns of the current 1st sheet on the workbook
Sheets(1).Columns("A:D").Cells.Clear

'Split MyFiles and loop through all the files
    MySplit = Split(MyFiles, Chr(13))
        For FileInMyFiles = LBound(MySplit) To UBound(MySplit)
            On Error Resume Next
            Fstr = MySplit(FileInMyFiles)
            LastSep = InStrRev(Fstr, Application.PathSeparator, , 1)
            Sheets(1).Cells(FileInMyFiles + 1, 1).Value = Left(Fstr, LastSep - 1)    'Column A - Directory
            Sheets(1).Cells(FileInMyFiles + 1, 2).Value = Mid(Fstr, LastSep + 1, Len(Fstr) - LastSep)    'Column B - file name
            Sheets(1).Cells(FileInMyFiles + 1, 3).Value = FileDateTime(MySplit(FileInMyFiles))    'Column C - Date
            Sheets(1).Cells(FileInMyFiles + 1, 4).Value = FileLen(MySplit(FileInMyFiles))    'Column D - size
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next FileInMyFiles

'Fit the contents
        Sheets(1).Columns("A:D").AutoFit

End Sub
```